# Is the name "Dov Bear" redundant?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

I know several people whose first and second name are "Dov Bear".

""Dov" means "bear" and well, "bear" is a bear! So the person's name is "Bear Bear". Huh??? What's the deal with that? That's like naming someone "Tom Tom" or "Ga Ga" ...

Wait a minute, there is a lady named "Gaga"...

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: What about Tzvi Hirsch, Aryeh Leib, Shlomo Zalman...

Comment: Voting to delete as PTIJ+OT.

Comment: @IsaacMoses - I haven't read through every nuance of our policy. Shouldn't all PTIJ stuff get deleted?

Comment: @DanF [It's](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/purim-torah-policy-allowed-but-regulated) not long. There's nothing in there about deletion. There's a [new discussion](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3490/a-silly-question-doth-not-a-purim-torah-post-make) about updating it. I'm advocating deleting this one because it's not only PTIJ, which is closed but kept around, but also inherently close-worthy as off-topic. This advocacy is not based on an existing written policy but could be suggestive toward a future one.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the name Dov Ber is a foreshortening of a much longer set of names pertaining to an old Yiddish Poem:

Dov Ber (Bear! Bear!)

Bo Ber (Come Bear!)

Bah Nana Fauna Poh Feher (In it, Grandma is testing the animals here)

Mi My Mow Mare (Who am I to cut lawns with a horse?)

Ber (Bear)

Comment: You got me off guard on this. Mineh Yiddish iz nischt Tzu geshtarkedicker, if y'know hat I mean. Can you provide a link for this poem, and I can see if I can get my friend to translate? I wish my bubbe were still alive to do it :-(

Comment: @danf Reread the poem without the translation... :)